# What is the intended replacement for .not() in Spring Security 6 HttpSecurity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In Spring Security 5 you can configure your `HttpSecurity` like this:

```java
http.antMatcher("/**")
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").not().hasRole("INVITED")
        .antMatchers("/forgot-password").not().authenticated()
```

In Spring Security 6, there is no longer any `not()` method in the new system:

```java
http.securityMatcher("/**")
    .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
        .requestMatchers("/").???.hasRole("INVITED")
        .requestMatchers("/forgot-password").???.authenticated()
    )
```

What is the intended way to negate authorization expressions like this in Spring Security 6?

Comment: According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html ... the `authorizeHttpRequests()` method you are trying to use is deprecated.  Refer to the link for details.  In short, the way you are *trying* to do it would stop working in SpringSecurity 7+.

Comment: @StephenC ah yes I see, but there's still no `.not()` when doing that.

Comment: I guess the replacement is [`RequestMatchers.not(RequestMatcher)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/RequestMatchers.html#not(org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher))

Comment: @MarkRotteveel no, that inverts the request match, not the authorization decision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no replacement, but you can implement one yourself:

```java
public static <T> AuthorizationManager<T> not(AuthorizationManager<T> manager) {
    return (authentication, object) -> {
        AuthorizationDecision decision = manager.check(authentication, object);
        if (decision == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return new AuthorizationDecision(!decision.isGranted());
        }
    };
}
```

This can then be combined with other static imports from `org.springframework.security.authorization`:

```
http.securityMatcher("/**")
    .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
        .requestMatchers("/").access(not(hasRole("INVITED")))
        .requestMatchers("/forgot-password").access(not(authenticated()))
    )
```